# Why the need for brackets for variables in a .m file in obj-c

Tags: objective-c

I've been using Objective-C for a while now, and if I declare variables in the .m file I thought I had to put them inside `{}` below the `@implementation` but I've just come across a .m file where they haven't done that, instead they have just put something like `int nn = 0;` under `@implementation` (although under the `@synthesize` instructions). What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

If it's outside of the brackets then it's a global variable, regardless of whether it comes before or after the `@implementation`.  E.g.:

```
@implemenation Foo 
{
   int instanceVariable;
}

int globalVariable = 123;

- (void)bar
{
    int localVariable;

    instanceVariable = 1;
    globalVariable = 2;
    localVariable = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code to show, it is hard to say. Technically, any valid C will compile in Obj-C. Since `nn` is an `int`, this would be perfectly valid c.